# С Windows на Linux, еще немного о C# и MonoDevelop.

Tags: c#, monodevelop, linux

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос:
В ОС **Windows** есть файлы с расширением **exe**, которые распространяются и создаются при  сборке проекта в Visual Studio, DevCPP и тому подобное. В **Linux** **MonoDevelop**, например, создает **exe**, но, как я понял, это расширение в нем имеет несколько иной смысл. Так вот я хотел бы узнать, есть ли аналог **exe** в **Linux**, чтобы можно было отдельно запустить собранный проект одной программой, а не тащить всю папку с проектом туда, где я хочу ее запустить, тем более, если в ней, к примеру не будет среды разработки вообще или она будет не совсем подходящей. Какое расширение даёт что-то похожее на **ехе** в **Linux**? Как его создать? Ведь как-то же программы в **Linux** работают...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mono myapp.exe
```

Почитайте [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851809/monodevelop-ubuntu-exe-file-as-output) и [здесь](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical)

Comment: Да, я знаю про такую команду, но без monodevelop-a на другом компе она не прокатит, нельзя ли создать эмм, даже не знаю как ее назвать... Штуку, которая запускалась бы, если ее открыть, как это делается в Windows-е... Да, знаю, что не надо всё сравнивать с ним, что здесь всё реализуется иначе, но такой подход там был весьма удобен и эффективен, неужели в Linux не продумали что-то подобное?

Comment: даже и в Windows, если вы попробуете, например, запустить программу, написанную на QT, без QT-шных dll она не сработает. сделайте инсталлер или даже бустраппер, который вместе с дистрибутивом вашего ПО будет ставить рантайм mono.

Comment: Хмм, вот это интересно, надо попробовать, большое спасибо.

Comment: > **сделайте инсталлер или даже бустраппер, который вместе с дистрибутивом вашего ПО будет ставить рантайм mono** 

@Макс Жуков вы это предлагаете в linux ?

Comment: А у вас есть еще какие-то варианты? Хотелось бы знать как можно больше:)

Comment: в линуксе принято ставить с репозитория пакеты и mono там будет с большой вероятностью. Ставить в линуксе пакеты не из репозитария, но которые там есть - обычно признак дурного тона (или тот, кто это делает, очень хорошо понимает, что он делает - например, нужна сборка с специфичными параметрами компиляции).

Для работы программы сам monodevelop  с вероятностью 99.9% не  нужен (если это только не плагин к самому monodevelop).


Резюмируя. Правильно будет просто сказать пользователю "сделай `sudo yum install mono-core`, если у тебя Fedora или `apt-get install mono-core` для убунту"

Comment: @eicto: `./configure && make && make install` чем не инсталлятор для линукса?

Comment: @VladD много больно пакетов стало. Без package manager'а уже тоскливо.

Comment: @alexlz: ну это да, правильно прописанная зависимость заменяет часы сомнительного удовольствия в поисках магической последовательности действий для компиляции на стороне пользователей. :-)